# How can Vika use an agiel?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

Vika is a mord sith, that is bonded to Hannis Arc, who - to my knowledge - is NOT the gift Rahl. We all know that the agiel only works through the bond to the Lord Rahl. So how is it that Vika's works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bond you are referring to was NOT created by [Hannis Arc](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Hannis_Arc), but rather [**Ludwig Dreier**](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Ludwig_Dreier). Vika believed her bond had been made by Arc, who was a wizard of some talent, but did not know that he had been propped up for years on the shoulders of Ludwig Dreier - a man who kept both his Gift and his abilities hidden.

Although we don't know exactly how Dreier exerted control over the bonds, he demonstrated the ability to great effect when recruiting his own Mord-Sith later in Chapter 38 of "[Severed Souls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severed_Souls)". To prove that he was a more worthy leader than Hannis Arc, he performed the following actions:

> - killed the existing bond, rendering all Agiels dead except for Erika's
>  - magically aged Alice, the one whom Erika pronounced a threat
>  - mentally controlled Alice, forcing her to lie in bed and die of old age
>  - convinced the Mord-Sith to swear loyalty to him instead of Arc
>  - reactivated the Agiels with a new bond to himself

Although we have only Dreier's inner monologue to go on, he believes that his natural ability alone makes him far more powerful than Hannis Arc, and he may be right. He has spent his entire life learning of the occult & magic in secret, and for a while hoped that Arc would prove an effective puppet. Once it became evident that Arc would not do, however, Dreier decided to drop the pretense and rule openly.

Given that Ludwig

> is killed by Kahlan

it will be interesting to see if any Agiels work in the final book.

Comment: Awesome. I thought there was more to Ludwig than they let on. I've just finished "The Third Kingdom" (the feels were real in with this one). I'm glad to see that they actually go into it rather than the excuse Vika gave of "We swore a bond to Arc, and here we are." I've also edited to hide some spoilers. :D

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - thx for the edit. And oops - I assumed from the question that you were caught up, but my bad if you weren't.

Comment: No worries. I'm not one who gets all upset about it. Especially one this minor. But others... lol.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to find it in the books (which might take a while), but there's a section where Hannis Arc goes over this (or his mord sith does).  Quite a bit of the magic and knowledge he has is super old, and not really all that understood.  He created a "fake" bond, that is enough to power the agiels.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that the secret or ability to do this was bestowed on Hannis Arc as a favour by Darken Rahl. Perhaps in return for the Box of Orden. He certainly gave him autonomy in other ways.

Sorry, it's a while since I read the series so my timeline my be inaccurate.